# Debian 8.0 - Cron job not working or not called.

Tags: cron

I have the following entry I put in after running `crontab -e`

```
*/10 * * * * /var/www/myApp/script/every_10m.sh
```

The script `every_10m.sh` exists and is executable. Just for testing purposes it has one line:

```
echo  $(date) >> ./../every_10m.log
```

When I run this script from command line it works well, outputting the date/time into a log file.

However, it does not run automatically every 10 minutes as suggested in the cron setup.

I see the following every 10 min in my system log:

```
Jun 24 06:00:01 ip-172-31-19-197 CRON[2517]: (admin) CMD (/var/www/myApp/script/every_10m.sh)
Jun 24 06:00:01 ip-172-31-19-197 CRON[2516]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working? why my log file isn't getting a new line every 10 minutes?

Comment: Firstly, why not simply `date >> ./../every_10min.log`? First running `date`, storing the result in memory, and then performing `echo` is less efficient and less readable. Secondly, it *is* running, as you get an error every 10 minutes. Is the script executable? Why doesn't it start with a `#!/bin/sh` line? Where do you expect `./../every_10m.log` to end up? Use absolute paths if there's *any* doubt whatsoever from which directory a script will be run.

Comment: You should really install and configure an MTA. Cron will send emails with the output of the commands it runs. Given that your script does run (according to the logs), it is highly suspect that it encounters an error, of which you know nothing about, but if you had a working MTA, cron would have sent you the error messages.